# Suppose $f$ is a non-negative measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int f<\infty$. Is it true that $m(\{x:f(x)=\infty\})=0?$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, self-learning

Suppose $f$ is a non-negative measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int f<\infty$. Is it true that $m(\{x:f(x)=\infty\})=0?$ Here $m(A)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of a set $A$.

I think the answer is yes. But my answer is solely intuitive. I tried, but failed to provide a rigorous proof. Could someone please give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. By positivity (or monotonicity) of integral. Let A be the set on which $f$ is infinite. Then for any $M>0$, $f\ge M {\bf 1}_A$. The inequality is preserved after integrating both sides, resulting in $m(A)\le \frac {\int f}{M}$. Now the result follows because $M$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\{x:f(x)=\infty\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\{x:f(x)>n\}
$$
and
$$
m(\{x:f(x)>n\})=\int_{f(x)>n}dx\le\frac1n\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)\,dx.
$$